# CodeIgniter with Summernote - Fail to Upload Image into Database

Tags: codeigniter, summernote

Recently I am trying to upload an image to my database by using [Summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/)

I found a problem when I am trying to upload different size of image.

Firstly, I'm trying to upload an images which contains **525 x 404** width and height and **39,9KB** of file size. It succeeded insert into my database.

I'm trying to upload an images which is more larger than previous one which contains **1600 x 1697** width and height and **743KB** of file size. But it failed to insert into my database.

I am using MySQL database. The field using **TEXT** to store all the content.

```
CREATE TABLE Newsletter (
    ID         INT,
    Content    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

May I know it is my database problem or it is Summernote limitation.

Thank you.

**Thank everyone. I solved my problem already. Just simply change the TEXT to LONGBLOB will do.


TEXT can only store a limited amount of data, where LONGBLOB is much larger, and is more geared towards storing file data.**

Answer (score 0):

Didn't use Summernote, but I would bet the problem is in size of your POST. Bigger the image, bigger the base64 string with image data, and your server probably has a limitation of POST size which is exceeded if the image is bigger.

If you are testing this in local environment, you can try to raise post limit in Apache config and test this theory.

You can try

```
post_max_size=100M
```

in php.ini, or

```
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

in .htaccess

EDIT: Don't forget to restart Apache after changes, and let us know did this help or not.

Comment: Still cannot. But I found a solution from others.